# Funcion postgresql con Tablas temporales

Tags: postgresql, funciones, tablas

tengo una función que tiene dentro 6 ciclos LOOP, necesito hacer un insert en una tabla temporal con datos que obtengo RECIEN en el ultimo ciclo, pero cuando entro al segundo ciclo LOOP la tabla temporal desaparece y no la encuentra.. ¿Como puedo hacer que esa tabla temporal perdure? Intente creando una tabla que no sea temporal pero tampoco funciono... yo se que si creo la tabla temporal por fuera de la función y luego ejecuto esa función anda, pero necesito que este todo dentro de una sola función

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes colocar parte del codigo que estas realizando?

Comment: @YeiroDavidBarrosBolivar Hola! es un codigo de mas de 300 lineas... luego del BEGIN creo dos tablas temporales, y luego tengo 5 ciclos LOOP. A partir del segundo ciclo LOOP la tabla pierde ubicacion, como si no existiera.. Sirve esta info? O necesitas que sea mas detallado? Gracias!

Comment: Me parece que una tabla física en tu esquema puede servir, si dices que aun no funcionada el problema lo tienes en el ciclo LOOP o en parte del código! porque no intentas registrar todos los datos en una sola tabla? es muy compleja las operaciones que realizan cada ciclo?

Comment: @YeiroDavidBarrosBolivar Hola! El proceso funciona asi: Tengo que registrar una cantidad de usuarios en una tabla temporal, pero para ello:

LOOP 1: Consigo la masa de usuarios, filtrando de mi lista total de usuarios
LOOP 2: Cada uno de esos usuarios poseen items X
LOOP 3: Recorro cada uno de esos items X, los cuales tienen otros items Y
LOOP 4: Cada Item Y tiene 3 sub-items Z
LOOP 5: Por cada sub-item Z tengo que revisar que cumplan con una determinada caracteristica y si cumplen los guardo en la tabla temporal (la que esta fallando)

Comment: Fuera de los LOOP: Luego esa tabla temporal con los datos XYZ de cada uno de los usuarios de mi masa tengo que comparar (por usuario y periodo) si cumplen con otra condicion extra de cantidad. Si la cumplen guardo en la primer tabla temporal el id de ese usuario.
 
Por eso no puedo evitar utilizar tantos Loops y 2 tablas temporales

Comment: @YeiroDavidBarrosBolivar Yo estoy seguro que es en el ciclo LOOP, por que intente hacerle un insert a esa tabla y dentro del primer loop va perfecto, pero cuando entra al segundo ya no funciona

Comment: Siendo así! tienes razón deberías trabajar con las tablas temporales: Pregunta: al momento de crear la tabla temporal colocas  ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS ?

Comment: @YeiroDavidBarrosBolivar Hola, no! Pero sabes que borre toda la consulta y la re arme y ahora si funciona!..Muchas Gracias por la buena onda!

Comment: Que bueno amigo! no olvides cerrar! saludos